# meteor reactivity breaks when using server/client folders

Tags: meteor

So I made something super simple to test out the reactivity in Meteor but when I came to make a server and client folder the reactivity broke. I can no longer manually edit the database and see the change instantly in the browser.

Template:

```
<template name="hello">
  <input type="button" value="Click" />
    {{#each tt}}
        {{test}}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

client/test.js:

```
Template.hello.events(
{
    'click input': function ()
    {
        Meteor.call('set');
    }
});

Template.hello.helpers(
{
    tt: function()
    {
        Meteor.call('get', function(error, result)
        {
            Session.set('aa', result);
        });


        return Session.get('aa');

    }
});
```

server/testS.js:

```
Test = new Meteor.Collection("test");

Meteor.methods(
{
    set: function()
    {
        Test.insert({test: "test 1"});
    },
    get: function()
    {
        return Test.find().fetch();
    }
});
```

What am I missing to get reactivity using this folder structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is an issue.

```
Meteor.call('get', function(error, result) {
    Session.set('aa', result);
});
```

This only occurs *once* in your case. `Meteor.call` is generally meant as a singular request, and is completely different than the publication/subscription model. The only "reactivity" you would experience in this case is if you manually do `Session.set('aa', result);`

If you want reactivity between the client/server DB, you need to set up publication/subscription code (see http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_publish). By default, *all documents in the database* are published to the client via the auto-publish package, so keep that in mind. This is to auto-allow you do stuff like `Collection.find()` on the client, which returns a cursor, and is reactive by default.

In other words, your `Meteor.call` is redundant. The `Test` collection already exists on the client, allowing you to do the following.

```
Template.hello.helpers({
    tt: function() {
        return Test.find();
    }
});
```